# Seq[T => Reader[E, State[A, Unit]]] into Reader[E, A]

Tags: scala, scalaz

I've asked some questions recently to find a smart and readable way to solve this more complex problem.

I need a super combinator with this signature :

```
def runStateCombinator[T, E, A](t : T, readerFactories: Seq[T => Reader[E, State[A, Unit]]], f : E => A) : Reader[E, A] = {
```

Don't worry, it's just a stateful computation (`State`) that needs some deps (`Reader`).

Here is my current code, any improvement are more than welcome (I'm a scalaz n00b).

```
  def runStateCombinator[T, E, A](t : T, readerFactories: Seq[T => Reader[E, State[A, Unit]]], f : E => A) : Reader[E, A] = {
    def transpose[E, A](readers : Seq[Reader[E, A]]) : Reader[E, Seq[A]] =
      Reader { e: E => readers.map { r => r(e) } }

    def map2[E, A, B](reader: Reader[E, A])(f: (E, A) => B) : Reader[E, B] =
      Reader { e => f(e, reader(e)) }

    val readers = readerFactories.map(_.apply(t))
    val stateReader = Readers.transpose(readers).map(_.sequenceS_[A, Unit])
    Readers.map2(stateReader)((ctx, state) => state.run(f(ctx))._1)
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general monad transformers could be a savior, but in such small piece they could only create lots of boilerplate, especially without kind-projector.

More specifically your `transpose` is just alias for `sequence`, which could need additional `Unapply` in case of `Reader`
And your `map2` could be refactored to simple applicative `ap`
Note also, that `state.run(..)._1` already have alias `exec`

And I've add additional `.toList` as `Seq` is not represented well in `scalaz`

Overall my attempt to simplify is

```
import scalaz._
import scalaz.syntax.traverse._
import scalaz.std.list._
import syntax.monad._
import Id.Id

type ReadState[E, A, F[_]] = Reader[E, F[State[A, Unit]]]

def runStateCombinator[T, E, A](t: T, readerFactories: Seq[T => ReadState[E, A, Id]], f: E => A): Reader[E, A] = {
  val readers: ReadState[E, A, List] = readerFactories.map(_ (t)).toList.sequenceU
  val stateReader = readers.map(_.sequenceS_[A, Unit])
  stateReader <*> Reader(ctx => _.exec(f(ctx)))
}
```

The monad trasformer, for example could make whole `sequenceU.map(_.sequenceS_`single operation without need of explicit result types.

Another option is to use monstrous [`ReaderWriterState`](http://docs.typelevel.org/api/scalaz/nightly/index.html#scalaz.IndexedReaderWriterStateT) with empty writes:

```
import scalaz._
import scalaz.syntax.traverse._
import scalaz.std.list._
import Id.Id
import ReaderWriterStateT._
import scalaz.std.anyVal._

type ReadState[E, A, X] = ReaderWriterState[E, Unit, A, X]

def runStateCombinator[T, E, A](t: T, readerFactories: Seq[T => ReadState[E, A, Unit]], f: E => A): Reader[E, A] = {
  val readers = readerFactories.map(_ (t)).toList
  val stateReader = readers.sequence_[ReadState[E, A, ?], Unit](implicitly, rwstMonad[Id, E, Unit, A])
  Reader(x => stateReader.exec(x, f(x))._2)
}
```